Cassandra SAI (Storage Attached Indexes) on Cassandra 5, Free Version
We want to utilize SAI on Cassandra Free version. To enhance search capabilities, we have gone through Apache Solr => Apache Startio => Cassandra Lucene Index. But these are not maintained, archived.
https://www.instaclustr.com/blog/cassandra-lucene-index-update/
We checked Cassandra SAI It was made available in Cassandra Enterprise in 2020.
https://www.datastax.com/blog/eliminate-trade-offs-between-database-ease-use-and-massive-scale-sai-storage-attached
https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cassandra/developing/cql/indexing/sai/sai-concepts.html
After going through documentation on SAI, it solves our problem of managing multiple entities. It is announced in Cassandra version 5, announced in September, 2024
https://cassandra.apache.org/_/blog/Apache-Cassandra-5.0-Announcement.html
We are using Cassandra with CQRS in our application and have multiple versions of entity due to filter limitation. We want dont want 'ALLOW FILTERING' and Materialized Views. So the only answser to have multiple filters on a same table is to use SAI. here is my question:
Experts:Is this feature recommended and going to remain free to use?

Yes, storage attached indexes (SAI) are definitely recommended. They have been used in production with DataStax Astra DB since June of 2023, and will be a part of FOSS (Free and Open Source Software) Apache Cassandra for the foreseeable future.
